# swfobject not working on iOS

Tags: embed, swfobject, twitch

I'm trying to embed Twitch player using Javascript API - here is documentation how to embed a player using swfobject - https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/player.md. My Problem is that the code works great on desktop, but on mobile browsers - iOS (I haven't had a chance to check Android yet) script simply doesn't  embed a video. It works when I use [iframe method](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/embedding.md) though. Is there any fix for iOS to make this works using JS API and swfobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swfobject is the flash player (swf = ShockWave Flash). Flash does not, and never will, work on iOS. The iframe method runs coder that detects the OS, and loads the native iOS player on iOS, and flash for everything else. You need to duplicate that functionality.